# Building SQL query on a one-to-many

Tags: mysql, sql, one-to-many

I have these tables:

threads:

```
+---------+--------------+
|thread_id|recent_post_id|
+---------+--------------+
```

posts:

```
+-------+---------+-------+
|post_id|thread_id|message|
+-------+---------+-------+
```

And I need to get something like:

```
+--------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|tread_id|recent_post_id|(array of posts WHERE posts.thread_id = threads.thread_id)|
+--------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Please, help me.

Comment: common, you've got it in you, somewhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to list column content for a group.

```
select t.tread_id, t.recent_post_id, group_concat(message) as messages
from threads t
left join posts p on p.thread_id = t.thread_id
group by t.tread_id, t.recent_post_id
```